# Getting kernel panic wth the message "not syncing fatal exception in interrupt"

Tags: 13.04

I just installed 13.04. Sometimes it suddenly goes to a black screen showing

> kernel panic not syncing fatal exception in interrupt

I have to do a hard shut-down to reboot the system.

Please tell me what's wrong in my system.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I turned off the proprietary drivers I was using and the panics seem to have stopped. Specifically I think it was a Broadcom driver that was causing my issue.

To get a full answer you'll need more specifics though. What kernel are you running? What is the full error message? Do you have any pci cards installed?