# unable to install ubuntu on hp probook 645 G4!

Tags: boot, hp, ubuntu-drivers

We have recently procured Hp probook 645 G4 for corporate use. On this laptop we are unable to install ubuntu. A similar issue faced by someone,so he has posted a query on HP support https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Start-Ubuntu-give-error-on-HP-ProBook-645-G4/td-p/7024937
which states to contact distribution support forum. any one has solved the issue or any clue in this direction would be helpful?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You should describe what happens in your case. For the kernel panic, I’ve found some answered questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/471012/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fails-to-start-with-a-kernel-panic, https://askubuntu.com/questions/315933/getting-kernel-panic-wth-the-message-not-syncing-fatal-exception-in-interrupt

Comment: I have no solution, only a warning. Installing in legacy is not an option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Enter BIOS
Ensure UEFI is enabled
Remove all securoty settings in BIOS
Check BIOS settings
Set Boot order
restart tap F10 choose boot from USB image
Install linux. Tested and works extremely well with Kali & Ubuntu even better than a mac.

If possible cherry on the cake - upgrade internal NVME SSD
Upgrade RAM to 32 GB (some say it may work with 64gb but I haven't tried.) Superfast and powerful machine. Enjoy

Sidenote ensure you are using the correct USB port to install from. Not all are the same.